# Upgrading kernel, Warning message

Tags: kernel, hard-drive

When I upgraded the kernel to the current version 3.19.0-22-generic I got the following message:

```
Jul  7 13:18:49 ubuntu kernel: [  717.001387] 
Jul  7 13:18:49 ubuntu kernel: [  717.001387] >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
Jul  7 13:18:49 ubuntu kernel: [  717.027764] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda2
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.188810] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.196740] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.205084] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.213526] FAT-fs (sda2): bogus number of reserved sectors
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.216658] FAT-fs (sda2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.231108] XFS (sda2): Invalid superblock magic number
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.245854] FAT-fs (sda2): bogus number of reserved sectors
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.250659] FAT-fs (sda2): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.269955] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.276130] attempt to access beyond end of device
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.276150] sda2: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.276161] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.281655] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.289335] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.289335] 
Jul  7 13:19:19 ubuntu kernel: [  747.289335] mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd
```

Has anyone here stumbled upon a similar message to this one before? It would be very much appreciated if you then could share your solution on how to get rid of it. In case it is to any help, here's my output from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x142c3bc8

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 461301759 461299712  220G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       461303806 468860927   7557122  3.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       461303808 468860927   7557120  3.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

and df -T (as requested)

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   1816944        0   1816944   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       365632     5420    360212   2% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4     226899324 67144904 148205544  32% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      1828140        0   1828140   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      1828140        0   1828140   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs       365632        4    365628   1% /run/user/1000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you do `df -T` in the terminal and post then [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/645771/edit) the post with the information. It may be helpful to figure this out.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from df -T.

Comment: I have found the bug on launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1374759). It seems to show up on even new Ubuntu installs with no solutions so far

Comment: Great, thank you very much for figuring it out!